# Reverse Template Alias

Tags: c++, templates

I need some way to achieve a "reverse template alias". So I'd use a template typedef to select the correct class to use at compile time. I'd like to do the following:

```
typedef ClassA Temp<int>;
typedef ClassB Temp<char>;
```

ClassA and ClassB are not template classes, but I'd like to select the right class through the use of a template. So if a Temp< int > was needed it would actually use ClassA. Is anything like this even possible in C++? I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
template<>
typedef ClassA Temp<int>;

template<>
typedef ClassB Temp<char>;
```

I got the following error in GCC

```
error: template declaration of ‘typedef’
```

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you want to achieve ? in your example ClassA and ClassB are concrete types, not templates.

Comment: And you can't template a typedef. but there are ways around that, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `typedef` can't define type templates, only types. The two closest things you can do are:

```
template <typename T>
struct Temp;

template <>
struct Temp<int> : ClassA {}

template <>
struct Temp<char> : ClassB {}
```

so you write just `Temp<int>`, but it's a derived class, not the class itself, or

```
template <typename T>
struct Temp;

template <>
struct Temp<int> { typedef ClassA Type; }

template <>
struct Temp<char> { typedef ClassB Type; }
```

so you can get the `ClassA` and `ClassB` themselves, but you have to write `Temp<int>::Type`.

Comment: Thanks! The second example is exactly what I wanted. I should've thought of that. In the derived class example, if I don't add anything to the template class, wouldn't it be the same as using the actual class?

Comment: @Justin: No, it wouldn't as it's still a formally different type. You could pass `Temp<int>` instance to `ClassA` argument but not the other way around.

Comment: How would I call new with this? ptr = new Temp<T>::Type() doesn't work.

Comment: @Justin: With concrete T it should work. But inside template, you have to explicitly mark dependent names that you expect to be typenames using `typename` like `new typename Temp<T>::Type ()`. That's because C++ grammar (inherited from C) is ambiguous without knowledge whether identifier is type or not and the compiler does not yet know for which T to evaluate the template, so it can't tell on it's own.